# How to use external database (postgresql) as input in streaming query?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to implement streaming input updates in Postgresql. 
Specifically , I would like to use Postgresql as datasource in stream input into spark.

Looking at the document, I was not sure if this is possible or not.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Would it be possible to stream input from PostgresQL, perhaps as a micro batch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stream your PSQL Data as a micro batch, **Kafka** is the best way. You can use Kafka connect (as a source) to established a connection between your **Brokers** and your **Database**.

**See Kafka streaming integration with Spark Streaming:** 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

**Kafka connect documentation**:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html

By this way, you can face to faults, concurrency and optimize your computation capabilities.

[image]